# Android drag n drop view

Tags: android, view, drag-and-drop, listener

I need to be able to "Add a button and drag n drop it to a location" For some weird reason I don't get any logging from my draglistener and I can only move from the left upper corner to the right bottom corner (!?)
When adding a button I fire the following code

```
@OnClick(R.id.remote_add_button)
public void addRemoteNewButton() {
fabMenu.collapse();
enableDragAndDropLayout(true);
View v = new ImageView(getActivity());
v.setTag("New button");
v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(60, 60);
layoutParams.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
remoteContainer.addView(v, layoutParams);

v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Timber.d("onClick()");
        ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item((CharSequence) v.getTag());
        String[] mimeTypes = {ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN};

        ClipData dragData = new ClipData(v.getTag().toString(), mimeTypes, item);
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

        v.startDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
        return true;
    }
});
v.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
}


private class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
    int x_cord;
    int y_cord;
    int action = event.getAction();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            Timber.i("Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            x_cord = (int) event.getX();
            y_cord = (int) event.getY();
            Timber.i("Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            x_cord = (int) event.getX();
            y_cord = (int) event.getY();
            layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord;
            layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord;
            v.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            Timber.i("Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
            x_cord = (int) event.getX();
            y_cord = (int) event.getY();
            Timber.i("Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            x_cord = (int) event.getX();
            y_cord = (int) event.getY();
            Timber.i("Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DROP");
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            x_cord = (int) event.getX();
            y_cord = (int) event.getY();
            Timber.i("Action is DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
            break;
        default:
            Timber.i(event.toString());
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Can any1 point me in the right direction? Cause I can't seem to find a decent solution. I tried numerous tutorials, editing the code cause some just didn't make any sense. Try out there "examples" but all gave the same result.
Any tips? Would be an awesome X-mas present ;p
Cheers, And enjoy the holidays all!

Comment: This sample may help you : https://github.com/Humoule/DragDropApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This sample may help you : github.com/Humoule/DragDropApplication – Farouk Touzi

Thanks to this comment I was able to fix it! :)

This is my solution to the problem:

```
public void newButton(){
    View newButton = new View(getActivity());
    newButton.setTag("New button");
    newButton.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_dark));
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
    layoutParams.setMargins(50, 50, 0, 0);
    dragAndDropLayout.addView(newButton, layoutParams);

    newButton.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    remoteContainer.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());

}

private final class MyDragListener implements View.OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        Timber.d("onDrag(%s, %s)", v.toString(), event.toString());

        // Store the action type for the incoming event
        final int action = event.getAction();

        // Handles each of the expected events
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                Timber.i("ACTION_DRAG_STARTED");
                // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                v.invalidate();

                // Returns true to indicate that the View can accept the
                // dragged data.
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                Timber.e("ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED");
                // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                v.invalidate();

                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                // Ignore the event
                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                Timber.d("ACTION_DRAG_EXITED");
                // Invalidate the view to force a redraw in the new tint
                v.invalidate();

                return true;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                Timber.v("ACTION_DROP");
                // Gets the item containing the dragged data
                ClipData dragData = event.getClipData();
                ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) v;
                for(int i = 0; i < viewGroup.getChildCount();i++){
                    View child = viewGroup.getChildAt(i);
                   if(child.getTag() != null && child.getTag().equals("New button")){

                       viewGroup.removeView(child);

                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
                       layoutParams.setMargins((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY(), 0, 0);

                       viewGroup.addView(child, layoutParams);
                       child.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                       break;
                   }
                }

                // Gets the text data from the item.
                final String tag = dragData.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();

                // Displays a message containing the dragged data.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "The dragged image is " + tag, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                // Invalidates the view to force a redraw
                v.invalidate();

                return true;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                Timber.w("ACTION_DRAG_ENDED");
                // Invalidates the view to force a redraw
                v.invalidate();
                return true;

            default:
                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}


private final class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        String tag = v.getTag().toString();

        // Instantiates the drag shadow builder
        View.DragShadowBuilder mShadow;

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("some label", tag);
                mShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
                v.startDrag(data, mShadow, null, 0);
                v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.performClick();
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```